# how to make a request to GCM to send a notification via XHR

Tags: ajax, curl, push-notification, xmlhttprequest, progressive-web-apps

actually i want to make a request to GCM to send a notification through XHR
I already make request to GCM using the cURL utility but i don't know how to do it with XHR. Is there any way to do that

Answer (score 0):

Good news! There's a dedicated page as well as a demo of your inquiry in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/step-08)!

Comment: The only info the dedicated page contains is "Another way to make a request to GCM to send a notification is via XHR. We leave this as an exercise for the reader!", and a link to the demo you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can not. At least, not directly because GCM API does not include CORS headers so it is not intended to be used from the browser. You need to send a signal to your own server and replicate the cURL command as the answer of that signal. See my other response: [How to send push notifications in Chrome(Progressive Web Apps)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36691533/how-to-send-push-notifications-in-chromeprogressive-web-apps/36717282#36717282)

Comment: As mentioned in d.datul1990's answer below there is a sample project that apparently shows how to send a notification through XHR. The following file from the sample might be useful: https://github.com/gauntface/simple-push-demo/blob/master/src/scripts/push-client.js