# How to send push notifications in Chrome(Progressive Web Apps)

Tags: ajax, push-notification, xmlhttprequest, google-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

Please explain how to do push notifications with XHR and Javascript. or is there any other way to send push notifications in progressive web apps. I have created curl command and when i execute it in my terminal push notification sent but how to do it on button click?

Here is my cURL command:-

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=AIzaSxUdg" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"cxA-dUj8BTs:APAvGlCYW\"]}"
```

This is what i have tried :-

```
function send()
{
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready
    .then(function(registration) {
      registration.pushManager.getSubscription()
      .then(function (subscription) {        
        curlCommand(subscription);

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send",
        headers: {
            Authorization: "key=AIzaSxUdg",
        },
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "registration_ids": [endpoint]
    }),         
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            crossDomain: true,
            type:"push",
            dataType: 'json'
})
.done(function() {
  alert('done');
})
.fail(function() {

     alert('err');// Error
});
})
})
}
```

But it shows error -----
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8880' is therefore not allowed access..

Answer (score 3):

Google API is intended to be used from a server so it is not including CORS headers.

As you are performing a cross origin XHR (from your domain to Google's domain), the User Agent makes a preflight request in search of the CORS headers that tell your client is authorized to perform operations.

To do this you need to make a request to **your server** (i.e. a `POST` on `/notifications/send`) and your server should then execute the cURL request to GCM.

Comment: This may now be possible with XHR. See Salva's other answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/36894224/1299792) for discussion.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
function send()
{
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready
    .then(function(registration) {
      registration.pushManager.getSubscription()
      .then(function (subscription) {        
        curlCommand(subscription);

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send",
        headers: {
            Authorization: "key=AIzaSxUdg",
        },
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "registration_ids": [endpoint]
    }),         
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            crossDomain: true,
            type:"push",
            dataType: 'json'
})
.done(function() {
  alert('done');
})
.fail(function() {

     alert('err');// Error
});
})
})
}
```